# Android RelativeLayout sync width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `LinearLayout` which contains two other `RelativeLayouts` (orientation horizontal). I don't know the width of the left `RelativeLayout` at runtime. Is it possible to sync both layouts? If the left `RelativeLayout` has the width of **100dp**, the right `RelativeLayout`should also be **100dp**. Or both should be **50dp**.

Can I handle this in the XML file or have I to do it via code and setting the `LayoutParams` to the same values?

Comment: are you asking if both can occupy the same portion of screen?

Comment: you could try a `wrap_content` and have the left `alignParentLeft` and the right `alignRight`

Answer (score 1):

set width of 0dp and weight of 1 in each RelativeLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:layout_weight="1">
  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's not possible, because both `RelativeLayout`s should have a space to to left/right. They should be aligned centered.

Comment: set a padding in parent LinearLayout or a margin in each child RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

If it's a dynamic width - there is no xml way of doing that.
In xml you can only:

1. set a fixed width for both relative layouts
2. set a fixed width of linear layout (or match parent) and for relative layouts use width="0dp" and weight=1

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the first layout is unknown, you need to use some tricks like that:

```
 firstRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            secondRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().width=firstRelativeLayout.width;
            secondRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```